# Deployment patterns / practices for hybrid api gateway and service mesh

Tags: design-patterns, deployment

we are deploying apigee hybrid runtime in a kubernetes cluster to secure north south traffic.
Are there risks/failures with deploying gateway in the cluster with backend services.
Would want to consider the api gateway and service mesh running together in same cluster.
Are there deployment patterns for securing both east/west and north south traffic in kubernetes cluster.